# Javascript XMLHttpRequest won't send with IE 8 or 9 but works with IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, xmlhttprequest

I am currently having a lot of troubles making ajax works with IE versions inferior to 10 while I have no problem with Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and even IE 10. My website just shows 3 select menus linked together, 2 of which get filled with data coming from a mysql database whenever something is selected in the first one and then in the second one. Apache logs don't show any POST request being done when using IE 8 or 9 and my select menus won't get filled with data.

This is my javascript code:

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {

   var xhr = null;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
         try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch(e) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
      } else {
         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
   } else {
      alert("Your browser doesn't support XMLHTTPRequest...");
      return null;
   }

   return xhr;

}

function request(oSelect) {

   var value = oSelect.options[oSelect.selectedIndex].value;

   var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
         displayOptions(xhr.responseText, oSelect);
      }
   }

   xhr.open("POST", "ajax.pl", true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhr.send(oSelect.name + "=" + value);

}

function displayOptions(oData, oSelect) {

   if (oSelect.name == "genus") {
      document.getElementsByName("species")[0].disabled = false;
      document.getElementsByName("species")[0].innerHTML = oData;
      document.getElementsByName("subspecies")[0].disabled = true;
      document.getElementsByName("subspecies")[0].innerHTML = "";
   }
   if (oSelect.name == "species") {
      document.getElementsByName("subspecies")[0].disabled = false;
      document.getElementsByName("subspecies")[0].innerHTML = oData;
   }

}
```

So far I have tried to change the xhr.open command from POST to GET, but without any luck. I also tried to put the absolute path to the perl cgi in the xhr.send command, but without any effect on IE 8 at all.

I have also tried the following thing:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(xhr.readyState == 0) {
      alert("zero");
   }
   if(xhr.readyState == 1) {
      alert("one");
   }
   if(xhr.readyState == 2) {
      alert("two");
   }
   if(xhr.readyState == 3) {
      alert("three");
   }
   if(xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
      alert("four");
      displayOptions(xhr.responseText, oSelect);
   }
}
```

This gives me the following output with Chrome:

```
one
two
three
four
```

While I have this one with IE 8:

```
one
one
four
```

Since I'm a newbie I fail to find what could cause this problem. I've been wandering the web for answers but still haven't found one.

Any would then be much much appreciated as I start to be desperate.

Comment: That's why JS frameworks exists..
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I think older IE doesn't like `.innerHTML` being used to populate `select` elements.

Comment: Why are you testing `window.ActiveXObject()` first - IE supports `window.XMLHttpRequest` from version 7 onwards (for basic support anyway). Also why bother coding a `null` return when the browser doesn't support it if you don't test for `null` in the other function? @CrazyTrain - that wouldn't stop the Ajax request reaching the webserver though.

Comment: @nnnnnn: You're right, though in the logging (alert), OP is showing a `readyState` of `4`.

Comment: Can you change the code to test for XMLHTTPRequest first? Gut feel is that on IE, though you can use XMLHTTP, you're testing for ActiveX, getting true and setting up an object based upon that instead.  Maybe there's an issue with ActiveX permissions on your machine etc.  You're catching xml.status of 0 which is 'not initialised' so a failure will output 'four' in your code.

Comment: I already tried this by just putting `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); return xhr;` in my `getXMLHttpRequest()` function. It has no incidence.

Comment: What do you get if you display the responseText rather than trying to populate the select box directly?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by using jQuery as Oscar suggested.

Here is the code I wrote that replaced the js functions in my above post, it works like a charm:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $genus = $('#genus');
var $species = $('#species');
var $subspecies = $('#subspecies');

$genus.on('change', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $species.empty();
    $subspecies.empty();

    if(value != '') {
        $species.removeAttr('disabled');
        $subspecies.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.pl',
            data: 'genus=' + value,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(code_html) {
                $(code_html).appendTo('#species');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $species.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $subspecies.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

$species.on('change', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $subspecies.empty();

    if (value != '') {
        $subspecies.removeAttr('disabled');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.pl',
            data: 'species=' + value,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(code_html) {
                $(code_html).appendTo('#subspecies');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $subspecies.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Sometimes using jQUERY is not a luxury that we enjoy.